# How to make the blank parts from the sides of a container shrink

Tags: css

Please look at this website http://www.grupottc.com/ scroll down until the section that says "VALOR AÑADIDO" when you resize the whindow you'll see that  the blank parts from the sides are shrinking with the window, how to make that effect, thak you.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). A website must implement some media queries to match specific max-width or min-width in order to fit the screen size. You may search for some of these queries in the website such as those below, which are only applied as long as the screen width is not more than 767px.

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
.elementor-column {
    width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 767px)
.elementor-96 .elementor-element.elementor-element-8g5lbx9 .elementor-icon-box-icon {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```